# Задача на подсчет переодически последовательностей

Tags: c++, математика, комбинаторика, теория-чисел

Нужно посчитать количество бесконечных в обе стороны двоичных последовательностей (из 0 и 1), периодических с данным периодом(не обязательно главным), при чем если последовательности получаются друг из друга циклическим сдвигом, не нужно их считать дважды (можно и формулой и кодом)
Например если n = 2 ответ: 3
…01010101…
…00000000…
…11111111…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, например, [так](https://oeis.org/A000031), если я верно понял задачу...

```
int a(int n)
{
    unsigned long long s = 0;
    for(int k = 1; k <= n; ++k)
        s += (1 << gcd(n,k));
    return s/n;
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо !